# Sending a JSONObject to a URL

Tags: java, android, json

I have an application which parse data from a localhost, I send one of the data (named `stuff`) to another activity (named `WView`). Now, In my second activity (`WView`), I want to send `stuff` to another link.
I used `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` to send `stuff` for the first time to localhost, and then I changed the object to a string name `stuff` just for the purpose of testing.

Now, the problem is, I'm using the following code. "add" in `postParameters.add(stuff.toString());` , has an error.

So tell me if I'm using the write way, or if it is wrong, tell me how to make it right.
I paste my code for sending stuff, from WView to another link.

```
btLogout.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(stuff.toString());
            String response = null;

              // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
              try {
         response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http:example.com", postParameters);
              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                     Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
                    }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct Syntax is :

```
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", Value));
```

In your case you need to change to :

```
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stuff", stuff.toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks, my second link is not up yet, but I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: I tried, but when the second activity (WView) is called, the application crashes. I tried removing the code for onClickListnere(), it works, but when I enable the onClickListener(), it crashes.